# What is the most practical python data structure for a time series of grid data?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I am working with a time series of grid data:

**'2014-01-01'**

```
0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
```

**'2014-01-02'**

```
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0
```

**etc.** ...

I have been using 3d numpy arrays, but I am not satisfied with handling the 3rd dimension as `datetime` objects, and would like to perhaps use `pandas` time-series for this.

Is there a generally accepted best-practice for working with such data in `python`?

**Update**:

I used 1s and 0s above to not make things too messy, but my data are values (of different types) over a geospatial grid (WGS84 lon/lat) over time.

I would like the ability to perform computations on the data in a date range on the whole grid, or some slice of the grid (using grid indexing). The `pandas` time series is nice, because you have the benefits of both `datetime` objects (with `.month`, `.year`, etc. methods) and `datetime64` scalar simplicity (i.e. data.date=1995).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'best-practice', it all depends on what the data represents and what you want to do with it. However, pandas' `Panel` looks like a good option for the structure you've posted.

Comment: @ebarr I have looked into the `Panel` structure, and I am a bit confused on who I might get the timeseries to work the same as with a 2d `DataFrame`. Could you suggest a method of doing this? I feel like I'm just dense.

Comment: date time objects are immutable and can, therefor, be used as keys in a python dict. How about a Python dict with the keys the datetime and the value of each key the numpy matrix of the geospatial grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) (or record array) would better suit your needs:

For example, if `n` is the number of entries you require and assuming your numeric arrays are boolean:

```
n=1
np.zeros(n, dtype=[('date','|S10'),('data','b1',(5,6))])
```